# How to use MYSQL Round function in a Multi-Select Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT bp.bizid, bp.usrid, bp.website,
ROUND((SELECT SUM(rating) FROM ratings WHERE bizid=bp.bizid)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ratings WHERE bizid=bp.bizid), 1) AS 'ratings', 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bzreviews WHERE bizid=bp.bizid) AS 'ttlreviews', bp.phoneno, als.bizname, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM endorsment WHERE bizid=bp.bizid) AS 'endorses', als.imgname, bp.`location`, bp.`ownership`, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM follows WHERE bizid=bp.bizid) AS 'followers', bp.categories, bp.openhours, bp.bizdecri FROM bizprofile AS bp 
INNER JOIN alluser AS als ON bp.usrid=als.userid WHERE als.usertype='Business'
```

**I am sharing this to help someone who might need it. I am using COUNT to count number of

reviews(COUNT(*))
follower (COUNT(*))

and endorsmentCOUNT(*)* in my MYSQL database. 
To find rating I am using Round function to help round of number to one decimal place after divinding total ratings(SUM(rating)) with number of ratings(COUNT(*))*

Comment: You should explain the problem with your query.

Comment: my query dont have a problem. i was sharing to help someone

Answer (score 0):

Because `SELECT` statements are invalid to use in `ROUND` function. 
You are going to need to use a delivered table approach

```
SELECT 
 *
 , ROUND(alias.ratings, 1) AS ratings
FROM (

    SELECT
      bp.bizid
    , bp.usrid
    , bp.website,
    , ((SELECT SUM(rating) FROM ratings WHERE bizid=bp.bizid)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ratings WHERE bizid=bp.bizid)) AS 'ratings'
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bzreviews WHERE bizid=bp.bizid) AS 'ttlreviews'
    , bp.phoneno, als.bizname
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM endorsment WHERE bizid=bp.bizid) AS 'endorses'
    , als.imgname, bp.`location`, bp.`ownership`
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM follows WHERE bizid=bp.bizid) AS 'followers'
    , bp.categories
    , bp.openhours
    , bp.bizdecri
    FROM
      bizprofile AS bp 
    INNER JOIN
      alluser AS als
    ON
     bp.usrid = als.userid
    WHERE
     als.usertype = 'Business'
) AS alias
```

Comment: This is totally false.  Scalar subqueries are fine as arguments to `round()`.